# Creating digital clock using a thread

Tags: java

I am trying to create a digital clock using a Thread as this seems to me the logical way one would do it. 
I am not sure if I am going about it the right way but what I had in mind is to create the initial current System time using the JFrame constructor and display it as text using a label. In the constructor I then create the thread object with which to update the time.

Struggling a bit and was hoping for some advice as to how to do it right.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation((JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE));
        setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel();

        //Font localTime = new Font("Lumina", Font.BOLD , 24);

        pane.add(label);
        add(pane);
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        date = new Date();

        s = sdf.format(date);
        label.setText(s);
        setVisible(true);
        runner = new Thread(this);

        while(runner == null)
        {
            runner = new Thread(this);
            runner.start();

        }
```

This is then my run() method to update the clock every second.

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            date = new Date();
            s = sdf.format(date);
            label.setText(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

Main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new DigitalClock().setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with? It also looks like runner will never be null, as you instantiate and assign a Thread object to it just before your while(runner == null) check. Oh and +1 purely for the rarity of seeing  a homework question that has actually been attempted before asking here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label state should be updated in the Event Dispatch Thread.

You need to add the following modification:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            label.setText(s);
        }
    });
```

instead of simply updating the label from the separate thread.

It's worth to have a look at the simple description of [The Swing GUI Freezing Problem](http://spin.sourceforge.net/problem.html) and it's simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to improve? It looks ok, `while(runner == null)` not necessary, you're initialising runner just above.

Answer (score 1):

Check this class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) is probably what you need.